# How to dispatch the action in dumb PrivateRoute component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to complete authentication process in my react-redux app. So far I have the folowing app.js file:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, isAuthenticated }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props =>
        isAuthenticated
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
    } />    
)

const App = (props) => (
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block1' component={Block} isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block2' component={Block} isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block3' component={Block} isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated} />
        <Route path='/login' component={LogIn} />
    </Layout>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.logIn.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
    pure: false,
})(App);
```

So, when the user is not authenticated he goes to login page, got authenticated and redirected to the desired page. This works well if the user has his account without limit of time. But in my app each user should have an account expired date. If his expired date is less than today he should not been allowed to access the protected pages.

Suppose I have the following users data in appsettings.json:

```
"Users": [
    {
      "username": "demo",
      "password": "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEOC26OrX6idwD+trnZ38fitcAWpRAM5wnfqo3KlVpi1Tn4JWArqJ6bCLyVRbiPDsWA==",
      "expired": "2018-10-01"
    }
  ]
```

If the user was successfully logged in prior to 1 October, 2018 and he didn't close the page in his browser he could have accessed to the protected pages after 1 October, 2018 because the ***isAuthenticated*** is true. It should not be like this.

How should I handle this case in a proper manner?

I see two possible solutions.

1. Add loginDate prop and set value for it in LogIn reducer if the user was logging in. Then in PrivateRoute component compare loginDate with today date and if the difference is is greater than 1 day, redirect the user to login page. But I feel it's not the greatest way to make it work.
2. After the user is successfully logged in issue a JWT token. Add Auth reducer that checks if the user is authenticated by post a request to the controller with a header containing JWT token. I already made this part. But how can I dispatch this action in PrivateRoute to get ***isAuthenticated*** prop value from Auth reducer?

Comment: can expiration date/time changed through the time(like "extend expiration to the future" or "invalidate token before it was going to expire")?

Comment: yes, expiration date can be changed to some future date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you need to dispatch action at some specific time. Or *after* some specific time.

When you log in you can run timeout that will dispatch an action(`'LOGOUT'` or what other you use - that will finally update `isAuthenticated` is store). With additional check if token has really been expired. If token has not expired yet(because it has been updated) just initialize new timeout and that's it.

Comment: ok, it's a third possible solution but I thought it could be easier just to dispatch an action that would check if a token is still valid **every time when the user goes to private route**

Comment: @DmitryS do you keep expiration date in store as well? then you can extend mapStateToProps for `PrivateRoute` to check expiration date as well not just fetch `isAuthenticated`.

Comment: I didn't think about storing an expiration date in the store. But I think this solution has a drawback. If the user's expiration date is changed on the server (in my case in the appsettings.json file) to later date, the user will have to reload the page to get authenticated.

Comment: @DmitryS I believe any solution running on client side will require to request server if expiration date has been changed on the server or not.